# How can I open a .feature file?

Tags: sharepoint

A coworker sent a .feature file as an email attachment.  I'm not sure what to do to open it.  It's a visual studio sharepoint feature file.

TIA!

Edit - Well, I tried something amazingly simple - I tried opening the files using VS2010 and they resolved fine.  :-)  Issue resolved.

Comment: Did you ask your coworker? It kinda depends on what you need to DO with it.

Comment: Of course... :-) Unfortunately, I got his OOO message, so I had to turn to the experts here.

Comment: .feature files are just xml files, so if all you want to do is view it, notepad should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Visual Studio 2010 should be able to do this. Although you might need to install the correct version having Sharepoint and the Sharepoint Feature Designer.

According to [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/visual-studio-2010-and-sharepoint-2010-support-at-last/) post, it should be built in from .net4 and VS2010.

Comment: SharePoint 2010 does not run in .NET 4, .NET 3.5 only. One of the most common runtime issues people have when moving from VS2008 to VS2010 is that the build profile might be set to .NET 4.

Answer (score 1):

.feature is a SharePoint SPI (SharePoint Project Item) folder within a Visual Studio Solution.

You can't do much with the .feature on it's own, you'll need the rest of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This extension is used for Microsoft Visual Studio SharePoint files. I assume, to open it, you'd need to install SharePoint (along with Visual Studio, which I assume you have installed)?

Here's [some information](http://www.downloadatoz.com/file-extensions/feature-file-extension.html), but it doesn't clearly state what program you can use. But I suggest, you ask your co-worker ;)